# "regarding", "according to" or "in"

Tags: word-choice

I wrote this sentence

> However, if the user defines each rule **(regarding/according to/in)** a specific context, the algorithm will take the context into account before deciding to remove such elements.

Which are applicable and what would be the implication of each?

I myself think "regarding" means "about" and is not proper here, but I doubt between "according to" and "in", because "in" is a collocation for "context".

Comment: Using "in" seems best to me, but there's not much to go on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*According to X* means "doing what X expects/says to do."  A context doesn't really explicitly tell you do to anything, so I wouldn't use this word (unless the kind of context you are talking about here does).

*Regarding X* is the equivalent of *considering X*, which means "to use X as a criteria in evaluation."  "Regarding a specific context" thus can possibly imply that the thing regarding is outside the context, aware of it, and can ignore/switch to a different context if needed.

Your full sentence if you use "in" would be:

> if the user defines each rule in a specific context

Is rule definition happening inside of a context?  If it is, say this.  However, it sounds like the rules are defined before the context is entered ("outside" of it), so I think "regarding" or "for" would be better.